# FieldValue.increment(1) doenst work as expected

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my code I want to increment the usage by the value 1. I have the usage in firebase and I use it in a chart. I use this function to increment by the value 1:

```
addActivity(
    int day,
  ) async {
    final documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid.toString())
        .collection('activity')
        .doc('${globals.year}')
        .collection('week${globals.week}')
        .doc(day.toString())
        .set({'usage': FieldValue.increment(1)});
  }
```

The problem is that whatever I do the usage value is always set to the value that is in the braces (now 1). I tested this with multiple values and it doesnt seem to work. When I change the initial value to 2 the value after tapping the button isnt 3 but 1...

I'm open and thankful to/for all suggestions :)

Comment: what is FieldValue.increment(1)

Comment: i searched for how to increment the current value by one and thats what i found so as far as I understood it it uses the current value for usage and increments it by the value provided but it doesnt seem to work or I misunderstood how it works

Comment: add the code inside that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That way it's written now using `set()`, your code always going to overwrite the contents of the document.  If you want to update a document, you should use `update()` instead to [update an existing document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data), or `set()` with the [merge option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) (`SetOptions(merge: true)`).

```
    .set({'usage': FieldValue.increment(1)}, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired effect you should use `update` method. `set` overrides data so it actually sets 1 each time for you. So, just refactor to this

```
.update({'usage': FieldValue.increment(1)});
```